# Flutter: add flavors configuration into Visual Studio

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-productflavors

My flutter application has different flavors.
In Android Studio everything is setup in the flavor configuration panel, but where can I do that in Visual Studio Code?

I guess I have to edit the configuration.json but I cant find any reference online on how to do it.

I do not want every time to type `flutter run --flavor app1 -t lib/main_app1.dart`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can pass additional arguments using a `launch.json`. If you don't already have one, click the Cog icon in the Debug sidebar and then select Flutter in the snippet-completion list. You can then add an `args` section, like this:

```
{
    "name": "Flutter",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "flutter",
    "args": [
        "--flavor",
        "app1"
    ]
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with: "--flavor", "red"

Comment: It was just an example of a flavor name - you could put `app1` here based on your example (I edited my code to make it clearer).

Comment: @AndreaMiotto it should be marked accepted answer :D

Answer (score 7):

You have to edit your launch.json file

```
{
            "name": "dev", // you can add nickname for it
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": [
                "--flavor", //flavor name
                "dev",
                "-t", // if your have different main file
                "lib/main_dev.dart" 
            ]
},
```

Answer (score 4):

```
{
  "name": "App Dev",
  "cwd": ".",
  "request": "launch",
  "type": "dart",
  "flutterMode": "debug",
  "program": "lib/main_dev.dart",
  "args": ["--flavor", "dev"],
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for me including both program and args worked.

```
{
        "name": "project (prod)",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "program": "lib/main_prod.dart",
        "args": [
            "--flavor", //flavor name
            "prod",
            "-t", // if your have different main file
            "lib/main_prod.dart"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).